# best way to integrate Elastic Beanstalk with AWS Lambda in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The last days I've been trying to understand AWS' products enough to implement a semi-large app. My conclusion was that I should store my files in S3, perform heavy duty on Lambda and the app itself should be ran through Elastic Beanstalk.

So, what I'm trying to do now is to call my lambda functions inside my app script, but I'm not sure on how to proceed. Should I use API gateway? I saw [an article in AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html#api-as-lambda-proxy-create-api-resources) that seems to do something similar, but it doesn't seem very straightforward. Is there an easier way through requests or boto3 or something alike? Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: "I saw an article" - can you provide the link? Maybe it already explains everything and the is no easier way?

Comment: Added the article. My point is people that have worked with  AWS Lambda on a Python app probably know the best approach

Answer (score 2):

The article you mentioned uses API gateway in front of lambda. This is the recommended way of invoking lambda **anonymously** (without aws credentials). For example when using JavaScript in your browser to call the function.

However, if you want to invoke your lambda function from EB environment, i.e., from a python running on an EB instance, then **there is an easier way**.

The easier way includes adding a lambda **invocation permissions** to EB instance profile. Assuming that you use [default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html) profile `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role`, you can add the following [Inline Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies) into it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow any script that uses boto3 (or any other aws sdk) to invoke your function through [IAM roles for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

Having this you can just use `boto3` on EB instances as you would normally do it on your local workstation to invoke lambda. `boto3` will know how to properly **get the credentials from the profile**, and no special action is required from you or your script.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! I'll be trying your option. I'm by no means a software engineer, I really appreciate the links to the docs.

Comment: @JuanC No problem. Hope it will work out. If something, please feel free to ask.